# Ensuring all changes saved on exit

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have a `Window` with a `Datagrid` connected to a EF object.

So far I have done the following to save rows after they have been modified:

```
   private void lookupTableDataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

However if the user closes the window without moving to another row, I have not been able to save the changes. I tried using `Window_Unloaded` or `Window_Closing`, but it seems that by then the `Context` does not exist anymore.

EDIT 1:

The following code is reached, but does not save the changes in the context:

```
   private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

EDIT 2:

```
    private CollectionViewSource viewSource;
    private OrderProcessingEntities ctx;
    private DbSet dbSet;

    public EditLookupTable(OrderProcessingEntities ctx, DbSet dbSet)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = dbSet.ElementType.Name.ToString();
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.dbSet = dbSet;
        lookupTableDataGrid.DataContext = dbSet.Local;

        viewSource = ((CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("viewSource")));
        dbSet.Load();
        viewSource.Source = dbSet.Local;


    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you show more of your code, where is your datacontext created?

Comment: I'm assuming ctx is your DataContext? If so, what is the scope and how is it declared?

Comment: @adminSoftDK  It is declared in the calling procedure and sent as a parameter to the constructor (EditLookupTable)

Comment: @AaronThomas ctx is indeed the DataContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WPF 4, property updates for datagrid happens only on row selection change, so to support the closing scenario without selecting another row, you have to explicitly set UpdateSourceTrigger for your editable columns:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Name"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Note:
I think setting *UpdateSourceTrigger = LostFocus* will work in this case too. The difference with PropertyChanged is that this will update the object at cell basis and some time this is not desirable.

Comment: I'd be interested in a link that verifies "Since WPF 4, property updates for datagrid happens only on row selection change." I thought it happened on cell commit, even in same row. MSDN doc on DataGrid class doesn't indicate otherwise.

Comment: @AaronThomas  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c38fc695-d1ec-4252-87b7-feb484ee01e4/wpf-4-datagrid-roweditending?forum=wpf and https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c71fe21a-6549-4dcf-aee9-43d02e73194f/datagrid-column-binding-updatesourcetrigger-default-not-lostfocus-since-net4?forum=wpf